# Don't include root directory in HTML tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, json, promise

I've written a function to create an HTML tree from JSON.

```
async function traverseTree (list, node) {
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  if (node.kids) {
    const
      ul = document.createElement('ul'),
      span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerText = node.name
    li.appendChild(span)
    li.appendChild(ul)
    list.appendChild(li)
    for (const kid of node.kids) {
      traverse(ul, kid)
    }
    return list
  }
  li.innerText = node.name
  list.appendChild(li)
  return list
}

;(async function(){
  const
    tree = await readJson('./tree.json'),
    list = document.createElement('ul'),
    output = await traverseTree(list, tree)
  console.log(output)
})()
```

The issue is that I don't want to display the root node in the HTML tree since it is already displayed elsewhere, therefore I modified the code to exclude it.

```
async function traverseTree (list, node, isNotRoot) { // additional parameter
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  if (node.kids) {
    let ul = list                                     // now let
    if (isNotRoot) {                                  // additional conditional
      const span = document.createElement('span')
      ul = document.createElement('ul')               // additional assignment of value
      span.innerText = node.name
      li.appendChild(span)
      li.appendChild(ul)
      list.appendChild(li)
    }
    for (const kid of node.kids) {
      traverseTree(ul, kid, true)                     // additional argument
    }
    return list
  }
  li.innerText = node.name
  list.appendChild(li)
  return list
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better, cleaner way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's separate it by responsibilities into renderKids, renderName, traverseTree so that:

1. the main function can start explicitly from where you want
2. functions become immutable, free of side-effects
3. less repeated code
4. a single `return` is used
5. hopefully, the intent and flow become more obvious

```
function renderTree(json) {

  function renderKids(kids) {
    const ul = document.createElement('ul');
    for (const kid of kids) {
      ul.appendChild(traverseTree(kid))
    }
    return ul;
  }

  function renderName(name) {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = name;
    return span;
  }

  function traverseTree(node) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    if (node.kids) {
      li.appendChild(renderName(node.name));
      li.appendChild(renderKids(node.kids));
    } else {
      li.textContent = node.name;
    }
    return li;
  }

  return renderKids(json.kids || []);
}
```

Usage: `const output = renderTree(await readJson('./tree.json'))`

Note, `traverseTree` is not asynchronous so there's no need for `async` keyword.

Comment: Modularizing code makes everything better.

Comment: why not make the function asynchronous?

Comment: man, although your code is cleaner, its wayyy harder to follow the logic, partly due to the fact that the names youve chosen for your nested functions are misnomers in certain contexts

Comment: and theres issues using your code because it treats the top level folders no differently than children folders

Comment: I can't agree. The code became so simple compared to the original spaghetti with side effects that "way harder" is an obvious exaggeration. The rest of your comments feels like a needless nitpicking and exaggeration as well. As for the "it treats the top level folders no differently", even without seeing the actual data I can't agree as it doesn't render the node name of the root which in my understanding was the entire point of the question. Anyway, this code was an example.

Comment: As for "why not make the function asynchronous?", there's no need. Even if you declare it with `async`, the function won't magically become asynchronous, instead it'll be always returning a resolved `Promise`, which makes no point, unless you want to confuse other people reading the code, of course.

Comment: I guess we disagree because you like the imperative algorithmic approach. My answer tried to demonstrate a more modern approach where each function is a simple block so its internal logic is easy to understand, debug, and maintain. These blocks have no side effects so at each point in the call hierarchy we are able to see the logic of this layer and predict the result even without diving in the called functions.

Comment: yeah of course its easier to understand each internal function block of code, but its so much more difficult to understand the overall flow of things. its recursion is incredibly messy and confusing. for instance, youre appending children in one function that are returned from another function, and then youre also appending children in a different function that are returned from yet another function. its literally all over the place.

Comment: i mean, the way its written may be good if thats all the function was being used for, but once you start adding additional logic, it becomes clear theres no rhyme to the segregation/recursion at all.

Comment: For me it's the opposite. The new code is way clearer, more straightforward, more obvious, the functions are used in an obvious fashion, the naming is obvious, etc. The original code for me was messy and spaghetti-like and it took a while to decode it. We can just agree to disagree.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how my answer is helpful to you at all so it might be better if I just delete it.

Comment: Er, I can agree traverseTree is the wrong name though, but I've kept it because it was yours :-)

Comment: like i said its definitely clearer in some ways, but unclearer in other. `renderKids` should be called `appendBranch` and `traverseTree` maybe something like `appendBranchOrLeaf`. its hard to name them because they share such similar functionality, so much so that u would expect them to be grouped together in the same function or something

Comment: "they share such similar functionality" everything here is similar because it works on the same data, but it doesn't mean we should lump everything together. Naming preferences aside, the functions in the new code correspond to the hierarchy of the data and the output, which is why it's so much easier to understand for me. P.S. Even more so if the `for` loop is replaced with `ul.append(...kids.map(traverseTree))` which I didn't use only to preserve more bits of the original code.

Comment: ok then we can agree to disagree. thanks for sharing your perspective nonetheless

Comment: it may just be due to my inexperience with recursion/this sort of thing.

Comment: My code isn't ultimate/ideal either, consider it a hint to use simple functions as building blocks and see if you can rework your real code along the suggested lines.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what im doing. i think youre right that chopping the code up like that generally makes the code a lot easier to read. its becoming easier and easier to read the more i work with it, and as i said before its so much easier to read the little chunks of code and understand whats happening. can you tag me in your responses so that i get notified?

Comment: you want to see what im working with now (i.e. how ive built upon your code according to your advice) and maybe you can spot some ways i can further improve it? theres still a lot more logic i have to add to it over the coming days, so better to make adjustments right from the start instead of going back :)